# How do I bind a dict as a preparedquery parameter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra

I want to bind a `dict` to a parameter of a prepared statement but I can't seem to figure out the syntax. What's confusing me is that it works if I use [positional parameters](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#passing-parameters-to-cql-queries) without a prepared statement.

Take a look at this example:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster


def works():
    id = '1'
    mydict = {'count': 1, 'value': 3}

    updateStmt = "insert into test.prep_test (id, mydict) values (%s, %s);"

    session.execute(updateStmt, (id, mydict))


def doesntwork():
    id = '2'
    mydict = {'count': 1, 'value': 3}

    updateStmt = "insert into test.prep_test (id, mydict) values (?, ?);"
    prep = session.prepare(updateStmt)

    session.execute(prep, [id, mydict])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
    session = cluster.connect('test')

    session.execute(
        'create table if not exists test.prep_test (  id ascii, mydict MAP<ascii,decimal>, PRIMARY KEY (id));')

    works()
    doesntwork()

    session.shutdown()
    cluster.shutdown()
```

The `works()` method inserts data just fine. However, the `doesntwork()` method fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/new.py", line 31, in <module>
    doesntwork()
  File "/new.py", line 20, in doesntwork
    session.execute(prep, [id, mydict])
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1569, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute (cassandra/cluster.c:26912)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1619, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute_async (cassandra/cluster.c:27219)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1632, in cassandra.cluster.Session._create_response_future (cassandra/cluster.c:27553)
  File "cassandra/query.py", line 411, in cassandra.query.PreparedStatement.bind (cassandra/query.c:5947)
  File "cassandra/query.py", line 536, in cassandra.query.BoundStatement.bind (cassandra/query.c:7678)
TypeError: Received an argument of invalid type for column "mydict". Expected: <class 'cassandra.io.asyncorereactor.MapType(AsciiType, DecimalType)'>, Got: <type 'dict'>; (Non-Decimal type received for Decimal value)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Just a guess from the error message, does `mydict = {'count': Decimal(1), 'value': Decimal(3)}` work better?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ah... that was not obvious to me. I didn't realize the `Decimal` in the error message was referring to an actual Class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run it in works() case, the driver under the covers is using string substitution to produce the following query, and submit it to C*

```
'''insert into test.prep_test1 (id, mydict) values ('1', {'count': 1, 'value': 3});'''
```

This is basically a dumb string substitution.

In the second case, multiple messages are passing between the server and client. Firstly a statement is prepared. Context about this prepared statement is shared with the C* server. The validation here is going to be more strict, because the context associated with the query is known to driver, and server.

You can work around this by using the appropriate type, in the query. Which in this case is the would be to bind mydict to Decimal values as suggested above.

```
mydict = {'count': Decimal(1), 'value': Decimal(3)}
```

Alternatively you could use an int type in your table like this.

```
 'create table if not exists test.prep_test (  id ascii, mydict MAP<ascii,int>, PRIMARY KEY (id));')
```

You could argue that the driver should be able to map from int, or float types to decimal, but that's not the way it works as of right now.

Comment: I didn't realize the `Decimal` in the error message was actually referring to a type of object. When I saw that error message, I tried using values like `1.1` and `2.0` but still got the error. So I assumed I wasn't telling Cassandra about the dict correctly. Thanks for explaining. I agree, int/float -> Decimal should be handled by the driver.